# TeamCity can't build a portable/custom targeted library

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I have a solution with a core library that is portable, targeted at Windows Store, .NET 4.5 and Windows Phone 8.0

This project will not build via TeamCity.

> [12:31:36][GetReferenceAssemblyPaths] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(983, 5): warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Is this a known problem or do I have to install something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Windows Phone SDK. Although the portable library offer's a bunch of platforms to be commonly compatible with, it still needs the relevant SDKs installed.